# What isolation level to use?

Tags: sql

Consider a trivial case:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test(id, value) VALUES (1, 'test'), (2, 'test 2');
SELECT * FROM test;
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

1. I want the first `SELECT` inside the transaction see the results of `INSERT` command.
2. I do not want other transactions to see the results of the `INSERT` command until the whole transaction is committed.
3. I want to know whether the usage of isolation level suiting the task is considered to be a good practice or not
4. I want to know how other isolation levels will affect the results of the first `SELECT` and what other transactions can see.

Comment: 1. and 2. will always apply - this is how transactions are defined

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I think, you are not right. I'm not sure, but it seems to me, that in case of READ COMMITTED transaction, first SELECT will see nothing

Comment: No. A transaction **always** sees (all) the change it did itself. Everything else wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation on isolation levels. It seems like you're already almost there.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. I wish I knew documentation with lots of tiny examples and that covered the example that I provided. From example, from what I've read and seen, it seems to me like `a_horse_with_no_name` is incorrect, but now I'm not sure of that.

Comment: The truth is, you probably want to always use read committed, *unless* you absolutely need a higher isolation level. Going lower is almost always a mistake (though to be fair, it's usually because people pick the wrong tool for the job - don't use read uncommitted to make things "faster"!).

Comment: @Luaan. Thank you, sir! From your comment I also start to believe, that `a_horse_with_no_name` is right. So, does it mean, that if I use READ COMMITED I will achive what I want? And are there any arguments against using the highest level of isolation - SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: @Luaan: not all DBMS support read uncommitted (and I never understood the need for that isolation level - it contradicts the whole idea of transactions)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 2. will only apply for levels READ COMMITTED and above, and won;t be true for READ UNCOMMITED level.

Comment: @JiriTousek: only very few databases actually support read uncommitted (plus it doesn't make sense anyway - it contradicts the whole idea of transactions)

Comment: Serialized means that you lose *all* concurrency on the dataset. There are cases where that is warranted (and funnily enough, it's what most of DB theory is based on), but it's likely going to hurt. Read committed is the default because it's a good compromise between consistency and concurrency - you can only see committed data, and you can only modify what isn't locked (e.g. by an update in another read committed transaction). You will rarely need anything else.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's part of the ANSI SQL standard, so... The trick is that if two transactions clash, the stronger one wins - if there is a repeatable read and read uncommitted trying to access the same data, the read uncommitted is going to be upgraded to a repeatable read. You still get rollbacks, you still get locks, but you lose a *lot* of the consistency guarantees. There's cases where you don't need those guarantees, but not a whole lot.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle supports it, so does MSSQL. Teradata only supports READ UNCOMMITED and SERIALIZABLE. That doesn't sound like "very few" to me.

Comment: @JiriTousek Oracle does **not** support read uncommitted. Nor does Postgres, Ingres (not 100% sure there), HSQLDB or Vertica

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I stand corrected on the Oracle part.